# Visualise/compare numpy arrays from Matlab/Octave to matplotlib

Tags: audio, python, octave, array-signal-processing, numpy

I'm new to python and matplotlib, and I'd like to visualise / compare 3 mfcc files stored as numpy arrays in txt format.
I have the Octave code below, and I'd like to know how it can be done using python/matplotlib.

Any help is much appreciated.

````
load /dir/k11.txt  
load /dir/t11.txt  
load /dir/a11.txt  

subplot(1,2,1);imagesc(j11);axis('xy');colormap(jet);colorbar;subplot(1,2,2);imagesc(t11);axis('xy');colormap(jet);colorbar;  

c=[k11(:,end),k11(:,1:end-1)];  
figure(1);  
Ncep=size(c,2)-1;  
a=real(fft([c,zeros(size(c,1),512-Ncep*2-1),c(:,end:-1:2)]'));  
imagesc(a(1:end/2,:));  
axis('xy');  
colormap(jet);  

c=t11;  
figure(2);  
Ncep=size(c,2)-1;  
a=real(fft([c,zeros(size(c,1),512-Ncep*2-1),c(:,end:-1:2)]'));  
imagesc(a(1:end/2,:));  
axis('xy');  
colormap(jet);  

c=a11;  
figure(3);  
Ncep=size(c,2)-1;  
a=real(fft([c,zeros(size(c,1),512-Ncep*2-1),c(:,end:-1:2)]'));  
imagesc(a(1:end/2,:));  
axis('xy');  
colormap(jet);
```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
# in python you will need to import the modules you use
# some users with matlab/octave background prefer
# to use from numpy import *, making all the functions global
# but with the time they learn (some not) that modules are good.
# you prevent overwriting an internal function with a custom function 
# for instance
import numpy as np; 

# for plotting we use matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
# load /dir/k11.txt  
# load /dir/t11.txt  
# load /dir/a11.txt  
## yow need to save the result in variables
k11 = np.loadtxt('/dir/k11.txt')
t11 = np.loadtxt('/dir/t11.txt')
a11 = np.loadtxt('/dir/a11.txt')
```

Matplotlib will provide basically the same functions

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1);
plt.imshow(j11); # or you can use pcolormap
plt.set_colormap('jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(t11);
plt.set_colormap('jet')
plt.colorbar()
```

Unfortunately python does not have a way to build block matrices, if you want to do vertical concatenation you can simply build an array from a list of arrays. Also instead
of using the keyword end you simply use negative indices, indices count from 0 not from 1, and you use square brackets to differentiate indexing from function calls, and you can omit an index when using a slice ending at the end of the axis.

```
#c=[k11(:,end),k11(:,1:end-1)];  
c = np.hstack([k11[:, -1], k11[:, :-1]])
```

For the above operation you could use [np.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) instead.

```
plt.figure() # I don't use figure identifiers probably you can
Ncep=c.shape[1]-1;

# the step size in python is the third so x[::-1] is flipping x.
# by default fft operats on the last axis (axis=-1)
# if I remember correctly matlab by default
# will apply fft on the columns (axis=0)
a=np.real(np.fft.fft(np.hstack([c,np.zeros((c.shape[0],512-Ncep*2-1)),c[:, :0:-1]]), axis=0);
```

I think with this you already got started, in the module `np.fft` you will find routines like real fft (`fftr`, `ifftr`), complex fft (`fft`, `ifft`), `fftshift`, `fftfreq`. And you find documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/)

Comment: That's a nice point to build on. Thank you

Comment: YOu are wellcome, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour make sure to wrap wen satisfied.